# Is my set compact in $l^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

I need to understand if the set provided by me is compact in $\ell^2$ or not. So I define the set
$$
A = \bigl\{ x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N, 0, 0, \ldots) \in \ell^2 : 
\|x\|_{\ell^2} \leq 1 \bigr\}, 
$$
where $N$ is fixed. So I have to some kind a subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $A$ is sequentially compact $\therefore$ it is compact in $\ell^2$. If the example is ok or not, can you give another simple example of compact sets in $\ell^2$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This a consequence of the [Heine–Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Comment: Compactness is a topological (i.e. intrinsic, invariant by homeomorphism) property, and $A$ is (homeomorphic to) a compact sub*space* of the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^N$, namely its closed unit ball. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._Riesz%27s_theorem